# how set store & call javascript values in android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In my listview if the user clicks on a item a webview is opened vieweing that file content.

The thing is that this content needs to be "readed" by javascript before it's shown

I have this javascript variable:

```
var url ="filename"
```

**filename** changes depending on the item user clicks on.

So, how do I pass this value from java listview to javascript code?

Comment: For now I store the value in a SD card file, It works but It has to be a better way because I have to use a hardlink to the file and that may not always work. External storage path can change depending on device

Comment: I mean what have you tried in terms of passing data between java to javascript ?

Comment: That's what I've tried. I store the value on a file in java and then I get the value from the file in javascript